# What is the meaning of the math expression in the periodic table example?

Tags: three.js

As topic

Here is the [periodic table](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=peri#css3d_periodictable) 1 example :

[code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/css3d_periodictable.html)
line 298,299

```
const phi = Math.acos( - 1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
const theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;
```

Above is a segment code of periodic table. It can calculate the phi and theta to create a set of spiral elements on the surface of sphere. It just looks like uniformed distribution. But I have no idea why this expression `Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi` can turn out such beautiful spiral distribution?

I thought it was fabonacci sphere, but it seems not. So What is the source or paper this expression based on?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not sure whether this is the right forum for your question: If I understand correctly, you're asking for the meaning of a scale factor. Are you even sure it has a deeper meaning? Have you tried using 1.75 instead of `sqrt(pi)`? I could imagine that one wouldn't notice much difference.

Comment: @Manfred I am not sure whether it's a ratio. sqrt(l*pi) in this example is 19.253. If I change the number to 5, it looks like this [link](https://i.imgur.com/ePMqkcS.png). No matter what variable l is, the result turns out uniformed spiral distribution on the surface.